# jquery slider not working on heroku, working on local with rails 4

Tags: jquery, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-slider

I am using s3slider jquery for images slide, its working fine on local, but getting error after deploying on heroku. I am using rails 4.

in browser console it shows

> TypeError: jQuery(...).s3Slider is not a function
>   http://rorblogtemplate.herokuapp.com/ Line 15

tried with many alternatives to call s3slider functions, but the error is still same.
 Aletenatives are as follows:

```
  :javascript
      $(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('#slider').s3Slider({
              timeOut: 1600
          });
      });



   :javascript
    Jquery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('#slider').s3Slider({
      timeOut: 1600
    });
    });





  :javascript
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#slider').s3Slider({
          timeOut: 1600
      });
  });
```

One thing I have noticed is that :

on Local the slider function is as

```
(function($){  

    $.fn.s3Slider = function(vars) {
```

and on heroku in Production after assests precompile, it becomes

```
function(e){e.fn.s3Slider=function(t){var n=this,r=void
```

Can someone help in calling this function in Production?

Comment: do you use a gem for the s3Slider? If so is it defined within the assets group ?

Comment: gem 'jquery-rails' its by default in gem file, I am not using any other gem for this. and its working fine on local.

Comment: to problem probably is that the js file isn't precompiled into the assets pipeline. If you get undefined in your chrome console when running `$.fn.s3Slider` then it isn't included in the pipeline

Comment: but when I see page source, this js file is there and its containing the slider code.
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-35c2a0340b82a310abcf4204e2e17ca9.js"></script>